# Use Amazon SES to build a marketing email system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Currently I'm working on building an email marketing system using Amazon SES. I have some problems which I have googled about for a while now but I couldn't find any clue so I decided to ask you guys here.

The first thing is I use only one Amazon account to send email, but it is limited up to 10,000 verified sending addresses or domains per region, so if I want to verify more than that I need to use different regions or Amazon accounts?

Next, is there any way can I add some custom arguments when I request to verify an email address? Because I need to check which account in my system owns that address so that no other account can use that verified address to send emails.

Any answer would be appreciated. And by the way, I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you in `sandbox` or `production` mode?

Comment: I haven't contact AWS support yet so probably I'm in Sandbox mode

Answer (score 1):

Email address verification is only required while Amazon SES is in `sandbox` mode. This is done to prevent people creating an AWS account and using it to send spam.

From [Moving out of the Amazon SES sandbox - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html):

> When your account is in the sandbox, we apply the following restrictions to your account:
>
> - You can only send mail to verified email addresses and domains, or to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator.
> - You can only send mail from verified email addresses and domains (also applies to Production mode)
> - You can send a maximum of 200 messages per 24-hour period.
> - You can send a maximum of 1 message per second.

You would typically only "send" from one email address, or perhaps a few to make it easier to handle replies. There should be no need for 100s or 1000s of verified 'sending' email addresses.

Once you request to move into Production mode and it is accepted, you can send to any recipients (whereas in Sandbox mode, each recipient need to be verified).

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your reply.
I'm using SES to build an email marketing service and use it for my marketing service which include marketing email feature. The problem is that my customers want to use their own email address as the sending address (I'm selling my marketing service)

Comment: Amazon SES might not be a particularly good fit for sharing amongst multiple customers, since one customer using it for spam can impact the reputation of all other customers sending emails. Even if each customer only use one sending address, there would be the 10,000 address limit. You might want to discuss your use-case with AWS Support. (Please note that support has a cost, but you can deactivate it later. And, if you're not running much a the moment, Support is very low cost.)

Comment: I realized that too. So if SES does not have mechanisms for me to solve it then may be I will have to use multiple SES accounts. What do you think of it?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "multiple SES accounts". There is an Amazon SES service, and you can use it with your AWS Account, but they are not SES-specific accounts. I _really_ recommend you chat with Support first, since finding problem early is much better than finding problems after you have built something.

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks very much for your help :)